# Table Structure using Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, css-tables

I want to create table with vertical and horizontal scrolling with fixed header and  table width auto. But this is quite hard to implement that's why I am trying to do this using div. I have written below code for this.
[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/Lm7z0258/5/)

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.tableContainer{
  border:1px solid #fff;
  
}
.tableheader{
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
  position:relative;
  
}
.tableBody{
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding-top:63px;
}
.tableheader .tablerow{
  display:table;
  background: red;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    
}
.tableheader .tablerow > div{
  padding:5px;
  display:table-cell;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
    
}
.tableBody .tablerow{
  display:table;
}
.tableBody .tablerow > div{
  padding:5px;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainer">
  <div class="tableheader">
     <div class="tablerow">
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableBody">
     <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="tablerow">
          <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </div>
       <div>
       Suspendisse ipsum diam, sollicitudin a tincidunt ac
       </div>
       <div>
       Lorem ipsum
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.tableContainer{
      border:1px solid #fff;

```
}
.tableheader{
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
  position:relative;

}
.tableBody{
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding-top:63px;
}
.tableheader .tablerow{
  display:table;
  background: red;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;

}
.tableheader .tablerow > div{
  padding:5px;
  display:table-cell;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;

}
.tableBody .tablerow{
  display:table;
}
.tableBody .tablerow > div{
  padding:5px;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Now I am facing problem with horizontal scrolling and column width.

Or

here is my another code [second code](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/extynaqf/). In this code I am facing problem with horizontal scrolling.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I have always found this difficult to do well, you could have a look at using Datatables a Jquery plugin for tables. It comes with a lot of this, and can be quite flexible. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Datatable does not provide filter like excel that why I have implemented simple HTML table but facing problem with scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

.tableheader add margin-right:17px;

17px is scrollbar witdh

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this, best way to represent a fully responsive table.

```css
/*
 Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty. This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px and also iPads specifically.
 */
  @media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #ccc;
    }
  }    
 @media
   only screen 
    and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
   display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
  }

    tr {
      margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    }
      
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
  td {
   /* Behave  like a "row" */
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 50%;
  }

  td:before {
   /* Now like a table header */
   position: absolute;
   /* Top/left values mimic padding */
   top: 0;
   left: 6px;
   width: 45%;
   padding-right: 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
    You could also use a data-* attribute and content for this. That way "bloats" the HTML, this way means you need to keep HTML and CSS in sync. Lea Verou has a clever way to handle with text-shadow.
  */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Secret Alias"; }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
  td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
  td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
 }
```

```html
<table role="table">
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">First Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Last Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Job Title</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Favorite Color</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Wars or Trek?</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Secret Alias</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Date of Birth</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Dream Vacation City</th>
      <th role="columnheader">GPA</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Arbitrary Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">James</td>
      <td role="cell">Matman</td>
      <td role="cell">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td role="cell">Lettuce Green</td>
      <td role="cell">Trek</td>
      <td role="cell">Digby Green</td>
      <td role="cell">January 13, 1979</td>
      <td role="cell">Gotham City</td>
      <td role="cell">3.1</td>
      <td role="cell">RBX-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">The</td>
      <td role="cell">Tick</td>
      <td role="cell">Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">John Smith</td>
      <td role="cell">July 19, 1968</td>
      <td role="cell">Athens</td>
      <td role="cell">N/A</td>
      <td role="cell">Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Jokey</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Giving Exploding Presents</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflow</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
      <td role="cell">New Smurf City</td>
      <td role="cell">4.Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Cindy</td>
      <td role="cell">Beyler</td>
      <td role="cell">Sales Representative</td>
      <td role="cell">Red</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Lori Quivey</td>
      <td role="cell">July 5, 1956</td>
      <td role="cell">Paris</td>
      <td role="cell">3.4</td>
      <td role="cell">3451</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Captain</td>
      <td role="cell">Cool</td>
      <td role="cell">Tree Crusher</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Steve 42nd</td>
      <td role="cell">December 13, 1982</td>
      <td role="cell">Las Vegas</td>
      <td role="cell">1.9</td>
      <td role="cell">Under the couch</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please check this example https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/extynaqf/ facing problem with horizontal scrolling

Comment: Hi @CodeBlaze columns are getting shrink when I am adding multiple columns horizontal scroll not coming. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/zLokhuqd/2/

Comment: Either you can prevent scroll or shrinking of columns. You can not achieve both a the same time.